# How do I find out if my C: prompt has been changed?

Tags: windows-xp

I have been trying to find out what all those programs are that show up when I turn on task manager. I am a newbie with computer stuff, so am trying to learn what is correct on my computer and what might be a virus/spyware etc. If I know what is normal, I should be able to easily see when any of that scumware is being attached to my computer.

I was on www.paretologic.com and they have a list of many of those programs. I found ctfmon.exe, csrss.exe, jusched.exe. I was also looking for smss.exe, jgs.exe, wscntfy.exe. Paretologic repeatedly says these programs can be found in the C:\Windows\system32.
I went to C prompt and typed in these files repeatedly in different ways, and no matter what I type in I get in return  "...is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file"

This does not sound normal or correct to me.

How do I resolve this? Any safe tests I can run to find out if C prompt has been altered, changed to something else?

Comment: Your question isn't all that clear.

Answer (score 2):

You have a misconception here I believe. The **command** prompt is not the content of your drive C:, it is for entering commands. C: is simply the current context for your commands. The reason why it gives you that error is twofold:

You would need to either change the current context or working directory of your prompt to the location of the files, or address them by including their location:

The command `cd <directoryname>` will Change Directory:

if it says `C:\>`

```
C:\>cd windows

C:\Windows\>
```

Try the command `dir` as well. It will show you files and folders.
[Here](http://www.7tutorials.com/command-prompt-how-use-basic-commands) are some more commands.

The second issue is, that running for example jusched.exe from the command prompt most likely will tell you nothing. If you want to poke around in your processes, take a look at [Sysinternals' Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653)

That allows you to get much more information on them. Be prepared to encounter a lot of things you will need to read up on though.

And be very careful what you do, especially in the Windows folder.

The "check what's altered" part is a bit tricky. A lot of files are altered for various reasons. You can for example make Windows check its system files for integrity, `sfc /scannow` is the command and you can safely try that.

[More info on SFC here](https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/system_file_checker.mspx?mfr=true).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find out if a running process is part of Windows or not, simply follow this procedure:

1. Get [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) and start it.
2. Enable the option **Show Details for All Processes**

   [image]
3. Enable the option **Verify Image Signatures**

   [image]
4. When you now open the properties of a process, it will show you who signed the executable and if that signature was verified.

   [image]

   Microsoft Windows core components are all signed by **Microsoft Windows**.

Answer (score -1):

okay I tried every one of those C prompt commands you guys gave on both this page and the link.  Here is what my C prompt box looks like.  (I am sure I have a problem now.)

copyright 1985-2001 microsoft corporation
C:\documents and settings\owner  (this portion of the line stayed the same for awhile)
I typed in behind owner cd
I received this "the syntax of the command is incorrect"

I typed in "C:cd receieved (...) is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

I typed in C:cd\windows  I received (...) is not recognized as an internal...

I typed in C:\windows>  I received "the syntax of the command is incorrect"

I typed in cd\ and it took me back to C:

I typed in >cd\windows\system32\   I received  "the system cannot find the path specified"

I typed in C:\windows>d:
I received "the device is not ready"

the last one I tried was sfc/scannow
I received a pop up box that said  "Windows file protection.  Files that are required for windows to run properly must be copied to the DLL cache.  Insert your windows XP professional service pack 3 CD now."

At which point I shut down the computer and started it about 20 minutes later.
So what would my next step be?  I bought the computer from craigslist.  I have no idea what a "service pack 3 CD" is, or what Dll is.

I apologize for this lengthy post.
Any help appreciated.  Thanks Mary